Spreadsheet database with html
Code.gs
function getShowData() {
 const sheetId = "1pP5hvkL81mBrFsbrqfs1iiAJjuOCuTZNVe78enWB7DQ"; // Your Spreadsheet ID
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
    Logger.log("Opened spreadsheet with ID: " + sheetId);

    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("showdata");
    if (!sheet) {
        Logger.log("Error: Sheet 'showdata' not found.");
        return { data: null, header: null };
    }
 
    const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    const data = dataRange.getValues();
    Logger.log("Data fetched from 'showdata': " + JSON.stringify(data));

    if (data.length === 0 || data[0].length === 0) {
        Logger.log("Error: No data found in 'showdata' sheet.");
        return { data: null, header: null };
    }

    const header = data[0]; // First row as header
    const body = data.slice(1); // Remaining rows as body
    Logger.log("Header: " + JSON.stringify(header));
    Logger.log("Body: " + JSON.stringify(body));

    return { data: body, header: header };


}

here is my   .html it cannot show data from spreadsheet
 <script>
        function populateTable(header, data) {
  console.log("Header:", header); // Log the header array
  console.log("Data:", data);     // Log the data array
  
  // Clear any existing table rows
  var tableBody = document.getElementById("dataTableBody");
  tableBody.innerHTML = "";

  if (!data || data.length === 0) {
    tableBody.innerHTML = "<tr><td colspan='" + header.length + "'>No data available in the table.</td></tr>";
    return;
  }

  // Create table header row
  var headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  header.forEach(function(colName) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.textContent = colName;
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  tableBody.appendChild(headerRow);

  // Create data rows
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    var rowElement = document.createElement("tr");
    row.forEach(function(cell) {
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.textContent = cell;
      rowElement.appendChild(td);
    });
    tableBody.appendChild(rowElement);
  });
}

function fetchData() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
    if (response.error) {
      console.error("Error:", response.error);
    } else {
      console.log("Data fetched successfully:", response);
      populateTable(response.header, response.data);
    }
  }).getShowData();
}<script>


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a [mcve]. The question doesn't include information about how the HTML file is opened.

What's the question? If there's an error, quote the exact text of the error.

It doesn't get error.I saw the execute in log Data fetched is show data from spreadsheets but the data in my spreadsheet not show in my  page .html

Showing data from Google spreadsheet
One of the requirements of publishing a WebApp is adding a doGet(e) function to your code. Here's a solution that would help you show the data of your Google sheets.
Modified script
function getShowData() {
 const sheetId = "#####"; // Your Spreadsheet ID
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
    Logger.log("Opened spreadsheet with ID: " + sheetId);

    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("showdata");
    if (!sheet) {
        Logger.log("Error: Sheet 'showdata' not found.");
        return { data: null, header: null };
    }
 
    const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    const data = dataRange.getValues();
    Logger.log("Data fetched from 'showdata': " + JSON.stringify(data));

    if (data.length === 0 || data[0].length === 0) {
        Logger.log("Error: No data found in 'showdata' sheet.");
        return { data: null, header: null };
    }

    const header = data[0]; // First row as header
    const body = data.slice(1); // Remaining rows as body
    Logger.log("Header: " + JSON.stringify(header));
    Logger.log("Body: " + JSON.stringify(body));

    return { data: body, header: header };
}
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('####'); //Change it with your .html file name
}

.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>no title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <thead id="dataTableHeader"></thead>
      <tbody id="dataTableBody"></tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
      function populateTable(header, data) {
        console.log("Header:", header); // Log the header array
        console.log("Data:", data);     // Log the data array

        // Clear any existing table rows
        var tableBody = document.getElementById("dataTableBody");
        tableBody.innerHTML = "";

        if (!data || data.length === 0) {
          tableBody.innerHTML = "<tr><td colspan='" + header.length + "'>No data available in the table.</td></tr>";
          return;
        }

        // Create table header row
        var headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
        header.forEach(function (colName) {
          var th = document.createElement("th");
          th.textContent = colName;
          headerRow.appendChild(th);
        });
        tableBody.appendChild(headerRow);

        // Create data rows
        data.forEach(function (row) {
          var rowElement = document.createElement("tr");
          row.forEach(function (cell) {
            var td = document.createElement("td");
            td.textContent = cell;
            rowElement.appendChild(td);
          });
          tableBody.appendChild(rowElement);
        });
      }

      function fetchData() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (response) {
          if (response.error) {
            console.error("Error:", response.error);
          } else {
            console.log("Data fetched successfully:", response);
            populateTable(response.header, response.data);
          }
        }).getShowData();
      }
      window.onload = fetchData;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Deploy your WebApp

Output:

Reference:

Web Apps


Due to the limited information posted, this answer might have some limitations. But if you have any questions with regards to the posted answer above. Please do not hesitate to give feedback, and provide more information so I can modify my answer accordingly.
